# How to listen for raydium and other pools live transactions in solana

Tags: web3.js, jsonrpc-api, dex

i want to listen to transactions from pools like raydium or orca and get buy or sell amounts and holder  address but im confused about the limitation of the rpc  , i don't want to use paid rpc even if i buy one it still cannot handle that number of transaction  im trying to monitor a big number of hot pairs
here's my current code but its not efficient at all for me :

```
const { Connection, clusterApiUrl, PublicKey, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL } = require('@solana/web3.js')

const connection = new Connection('https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/', { commitment: 'confirmed' })
const transactionConnection = new Connection('https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/', { commitment: 'confirmed' })
const programId = new PublicKey('tokenprogramid')
async function fn2(signature){


  const transaction = await transactionConnection.getParsedTransaction(signature, {commitment:'confirmed' , maxSupportedTransactionVersion:0})
  if (!transaction ){return false}
// other code to parse amounts 
  }

connection.onProgramAccountChange(programId, async (logs) => {
  fn2(logs.signature);
} , 'confirmed');
```

Comment: Does https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/9052/listen-to-raydium-swap-transactions-via-websocket answer your question?

Comment: i tried to log them before , but i could  not find any of the amounts just gas fees used to procced the transaction , i could get the signature from it and get the transaction but its not possible since the limitation of the rpc

Comment: Ah gotcha, in that case, you may want to look into setting up your own node and using geyser plugins: https://docs.solanalabs.com/validator/geyser that way you get all the info right away